# Нужна ли здесь запятая (обособление сравнительного оборота)?

Tags: сравнительный-оборот

*Резкий стук в окно раздался **как оглушительный выстрел из ружья**.*

Это предложение с другого ресурса. Пятеро участников сказали, что не нужна. А вы как думаете? Ответ желательно обосновать.

Спасибо.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138782/discussion-on-question-by-sharon------).

Answer (score 3):

С одной стороны, хотелось бы сделать сравнение, поставив запятую.

Но с другой вот что:
Порядок слов указывает на то, что об этом стуке уже говорили, что о нём известно. В таком случае нежелательно делать ударение на глаголе, так как он не несёт новую информацию. Например:
*Он быстро бегает. Он бегает как гепАрд.*

Чем несамостоятельнее глагол, тем это актуальнее (а "раздаться" самостоятельностью не отличается). У Розенталя несамостоятельность описывается так: "сказуемое не выражает необходимого смысла без сравнительного оборота". Вот здесь более явно:
*Я услышал громкий стук. Он раздался как грОм.* || И так понятно, что стук раздался, нового нет в этом глаголе, незачем его подчёркивать, оборот выходит на первый план.

Answer (score 3):

Такое построение предложения и его члены вокруг слова "стук" указывают на **первое упоминание** об этом самом стуке.

*Резкий стук в окнО раздался как оглушительный выстрел из ружья.*

Как можно ещё выразить эту же мысль этими же словами?

*Как оглушительный выстрел из ружьЯ, раздАлся резкий стук в окно.*

В варианте из вопроса, как верно отметил oleedd, глаголу уже выпячиваться не надо, паузы перед оборотом нет. Основное внимание и тонический акцент – на словосочетании "резкий стук в окно".
Во втором варианте есть место для выделения глагола, запятая ставится, так как без неё мы будем описывать глагол (как именно?, каким образом?), но состав предложения, в частности определение "резкий", не позволяет так поступить.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138779/discussion-on-answer-by--------).

Answer (score 3):

**Благодарю отвечающих за их мнение** (голоса мои), но, к сожалению, я думаю иначе.

1. Чем более **распространённым** является оборот, тем больше у него шансов быть обособленным.
2. **При нормальном порядке слов** обособление оборота не вызывает сомнения: *Раздался резкий стУк в окно, **как оглушительный выстрел из ружья**.*
3. В приведенном предложении порядок слов изменен в соответствии с контекстом, поэтому нужен **анализ.**

Но что меня абсолютно не устраивает в рассуждениях, так это **«несамостоятельность глагола».** Этот термин мне вообще непонятен –  на обособление может повлиять только **лексическая невыраженность** глагола.  Всё остальное – из области ощущений, как мне думается.

Здесь же оборот имеет явное значение **уподобления** (стук сравнивается с выстрелом; союз КАК можно заменить союзом СЛОВНО).

4. Поэтому обособление оборота зависит **только от структуры предложения** и расстановки ударений – так мы проверяем **возможность** его обособления:

*Резкий стУк в окно раздался, **как (словно) оглушительный выстрел из ружья**.*

При такой постановке ударений **грамматическая пауза слышится явно** и обозначается запятой.

**5. Похожие примеры:**

*ВторОй удар раздался, **как выстрел из ружья**, и напоминал бой старинных часов в гостиной* (рассказ «Молоточек»).

*Ливень сбежал с побережья в море. ГрОм ударил, **как выстрел из пушки**.* [В. П. Катаев. Море (1928)]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138780/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------).

Answer (score 1):

Меня вдруг осенило. Этот ответ уже совпадает с вашим мнением.

Изымаем оборот:
*Резкий стук в окно раздался.* || Так можно написать, нужный смысл выражает. Значит, оборот не входит в сказуемое.
Сравнить: *Резкий стук в окно звучал как оглушительный выстрел из ружья.* || Здесь входит в сказуемое.
Ситуации очень похожие, отсюда путаница.

Идём дальше:
*Резкий стук в окно раздался оглушительным выстрелом из ружья.* || Это бред. Стук не выстрел. Не похоже на обстоятельство. Вопрос "как?" не очень подходит. Больше подходит "подобно чему?".

Поэтому ставим запятую.

Если о стуке уже говорили, то оборот выходит на первый план:
*Тот резкий стук в окно раздался как оглушительный выстрел из ружьЯ.* || Разве что так.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138781/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd------).

Comment: Ответ не противоречит предыдущему.